# cs-script Unexpected character "$"

Tags: cs-script

Use cs-script in a console app with

`dynamic script = CSScript.LoadCode(
                           @"using System;
                             public class Script
                             {
                                 public void SayHello(string name)
                                 {
                                    Console.WriteLine($""Hello: {name}!"");
                                 }
                             }")
                             .CreateObject("*");
            script.SayHello("World");`

Unexpected character "$" exception throwed.
But the following code do well.

```
            dynamic script = CSScript.Evaluator.LoadCode(
                        @"using System;
                         public class Script
                         {
                             public void SayHello(string name)
                             {
                                Console.WriteLine($""Hello: {name}！"");
                             }
                         }");

        script.SayHello("World");
```

And i hnow CSScript.Evaluator is more solwer.How can i use the syntax sugar faster?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but your workaround with using evaluator helped me!